# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed while inserting more than 1 record

Tags: android

I got this error when I insert data for 2nd time. It works fine for 1st time I insert data in database. But later my app gets forced close or item added but not display in listview.
My logcat looks like when I try to insert 2nd record

```
05-06 04:14:06.220: E/SQLiteDatabase(773): Error inserting imei_id=0 c_addr=54     i_date=6/5/2013 c_nm=rte e_date=6/5/2013 cl_no=tre exe_flg=true l_no=65 l_type=dfdg
05-06 04:14:06.220: E/SQLiteDatabase(773): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
05-06 04:14:06.220: E/SQLiteDatabase(773):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
05-06 04:14:06.220: E/SQLiteDatabase(773):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
05-06 04:14:06.220: E/SQLiteDatabase(773):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
05-06 04:14:06.220: E/SQLiteDatabase(773):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
05-06 04:14:06.220: E/SQLiteDatabase(773):  at com.smartwallet.database.DbAdapterDLicense.insertDL(DbAdapterDLicense.java:49)
05-06 04:14:06.220: E/SQLiteDatabase(773):  at com.exampl.smartwallet.Add_DLicense.onClick(Add_DLicense.java:139)
```

my class to add record is

```
package com.exampl.smartwallet;

import java.util.Calendar;

import com.smartwallet.database.DbAdapterDLicense;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Add_DLicense extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
private TextView et_idt,et_edt;
private EditText et_cnm,et_lno,et_add,et_cno,et_ltype;
private Button bt_add;
private Long dlid,l;    
private int mYear,mMonth, mDay;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_IDI = 0;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_IDE = 1;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListenerI;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListenerE;
private DbAdapterDLicense DBA;
//private TelephonyManager tm;
private String imei="9898";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b) 
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_dlicense);
    dlid=null;
    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();

    dlid=(b==null)? null:(Long)b.getSerializable("imei_id");
    if(extras!=null)
    {
        dlid=extras.getLong("imei_id");
    }

    DBA=new DbAdapterDLicense(this);
    DBA.open();


    et_cnm=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_cnm);
    et_idt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.et_idt);
    et_edt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.et_edt);
    et_lno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_lno);
    et_add=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_add);
    et_cno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_cno);
    et_ltype=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_ltype);
    et_idt.setOnClickListener(this);
    et_edt.setOnClickListener(this);

    bt_add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_save);

    bt_add.setOnClickListener(this);        

    mDateSetListenerI = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
    {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
            {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay1();
            }
        };

        final Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        updateDisplay1();
        mDateSetListenerE = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
        {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
                {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay2();
                }
            };

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    updateDisplay2();
}

public boolean validate() {

    if(et_cnm.getText().toString().equals(""))
        return false;
    if(et_lno.getText().toString().equals(""))
        return false;
    if(et_add.getText().toString().equals(""))
        return false;
    if(et_cno.getText().toString().equals(""))
        return false;
    if(et_ltype.getText().toString().equals(""))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
     if(v.equals(et_idt))
        {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_IDI);
        }
         if(v.equals(et_edt))
        {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_IDE);
        }

    if(!validate()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Blank fields are not allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if(v.equals(bt_add))
    {
        if(dlid==null)
        {
            l = DBA.insertDL(0, et_cnm.getText().toString(),et_idt.getText().toString(),et_edt.getText().toString(),et_lno.getText().toString(),et_add.getText().toString(),et_cno.getText().toString(),et_ltype.getText().toString(),"true");
            Toast.makeText(Add_DLicense.this, "Item Added", 2000).show();
            imei+=l;
            //DBA.updateDL(l, Long.parseLong(imei), et_cnm.getText().toString(),et_idt.getText().toString(),et_edt.getText().toString(),et_lno.getText().toString(), et_add.getText().toString(),et_cno.getText().toString(),et_ltype.getText().toString(),"true");
        }
        finish();
    }

}
private void updateDisplay1() 
{
    et_idt.setText(""+mDay+"/"+(mMonth+1)+"/"+mYear);   
}
private void updateDisplay2() 
{
    et_edt.setText(""+mDay+"/"+(mMonth+1)+"/"+mYear);   
}

 @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
    {
        if(id==DATE_DIALOG_IDI)
        {
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    mDateSetListenerI,
                    mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        }
        else if(id==DATE_DIALOG_IDE)
        {
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    mDateSetListenerE,
                    mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        }
        return null;
    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DBA.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

and DbAdapter query is

```
public long insertDL(long imei_id,String c_nm,String i_date, String e_date,String l_no,String cl_no,String c_addr,String l_type,String exe_flg) 
{
    ContentValues values = createContentValues_dl(imei_id,c_nm,i_date, e_date, l_no,cl_no,c_addr,l_type,exe_flg);
    return db.insert(T_DLICENSE, null, values);
}
```

and table in CreateTable is

```
private static final String DRIVINGLICENSE 
= "create table DrivingLicense " +
"(dlid integer primary key autoincrement, " +
"imei_id int(20), " +
"c_nm text not null,"+
"i_date text not null, " +
"e_date text not null,"+
"l_no text not null,"+
"cl_no text not null,"+
"c_addr text not null,"+
"exe_flg text not null,"+
"l_type text not null,UNIQUE(imei_id));";
```

please help me in inserting more than one record . I already search but faild to find solution. Because 1st record inserted correctly but not more than that ... Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting the same value for the column `imei_id` You cannot do so as it is declared unique.

Comment: do not hardcode the "imei_id" value. increment the value at every insertion. why do you have it anyway? as u hardcode it to 0?

Comment: is there any other solution??

Comment: create the table removing "UNIQUE(imei_id)". It too should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Failed constraint mean that your insertion is violating the constraints you specified in the table creation. In your case this is that a lot of fields are not null, one is a key, and one is unique. What you should do here, is use a debugger, stop the code just before the insertion and check all the values are what you expect, and meet your constraints.

One thing you might want to check is the field imei_id - you specify it is to be unique, yet it seems your call to function insertDL has this as the constant 0..